# Как вывести картинку на сайт(golang)?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, golang

Я делаю сайт на golang. Мне понадобилось вывести изображение в формате jpg. Прописал в html файле:

```
<img src="1.jpg" alt="img err">
```

Получаю "img err", в Main.go пишу

```
template.ParseFiles("1.jpg")
```

Вывожу через шаблонизатор, получаю nil на странице. Пишу

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "1.jpg")
```

Выводиться как текст. Пишу

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<img src='1.jpg' alt='img err'")
```

И получаю, что вы думаете? IMG ERR!!!

Как все таки вывести эту проклятую картинку???

*Также хочу отметить что не работает подключение js через тег script src. А так же не работает подключение css через link.

Comment: Где пишете, что такое `template`, что такое `w`? Ничего не понятно, покажите [mcve]

Comment: Каким фреймворком пользуетесь? Если gin, то статический контент надо явным образом добавлять: `router.StaticFile("/1.jpg", "path/to/1.jpg")`, более подробный пример типов статического контента https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/serving-static-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем точный вопрос. Но в общем случаем когда нужно вывести на страницу изображение можно действовать так:

В обработчике реквестов добавьте директорию файлы из которой будут доступны в вебе

```
http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))))
```

в данном случаем это папка assets, создайте её рядом с исполняемым файлом
и в неё положите свой файл "1.jpg"
и на странице выведите

```
<img src="assets/1.jpg" alt="img err">
```

Будьте внимательны, в данном исполнении все файлы папки assets общедоступны